# sendAsynchronousRequest deprecated in iOS 9, how do I fix my function

Tags: ios, swift

An extension on my `UIImageView` is giving me a warning. I would like a warning free project but I'm not sure how to fix this properly. The warning I receive is this:

> sendAsynchronousRequest was depricated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession
>   dataTAskWithRequest....

The extension that's causing the warning is this:

```
extension UIImageView {
    public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString) {
            let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
                (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if let imageData = data as NSData? {
                    self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for

**Swift 3.0**

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, error in
   if (error == nil) {
      //Do needful things // Your code . . . 
   } else {
      print("Error : \(error?.localizedDescription)");
   }
}.resume();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your warning clearly says that `sendAsynchronousRequest was depricated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTAskWithRequest` that means you should use `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection`!!!

You should do something like,

```
 var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print("Response: \(response)")})

task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4.0** use this:

```
let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "URL Here")!)

let session = URLSession.shared
let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in

    do {
        //your code here
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }

})

task.resume()
```